# Equals operator for part of a result

Tags: mysql, database

I have a question that I think is best asked by example.

Say I have a table that lists states and all the cities in each state. In my example, I am looking for which state Little Rock belongs to. I would obviously use the equals operator and where statement to find out that it belongs to Arkansas. However, maybe I can't remember the full name of "Little Rock". I know it's something Rock but I can't remember if it was Big, Little, Yellow or Purple. Is there a way to search just for "Rock" under cities?

Thanks!

Nicolle

PS I am using MySQL

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/pattern-matching.html

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the [LIKE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) operator. When using `LIKE` you can use `%` as a wildcard.

```
SELECT * FROM states WHERE state LIKE "%Rock"
```

> Say there was a city called Yellow Big Purple Little Rock of New Arkansas. Would the query look similar?

In this case, you could use another `%` for a wildcard after "Rock".

```
SELECT * FROM states WHERE state LIKE "%Rock%"
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! If 'rock' is submerged in more words, does it still work?

Say there was a city called Yellow Big Purple Little Rock of New Arkansas. Would the query look similar?